# Create Multi User Group with Prosody Server on Android (aSmack) failes with "Missing acknowledge of room creation"

Tags: xmpp, smack, multiuserchat, prosody-im

i am working on XMPP chat app in android, using `Prosody` as `XMPP server`.
i have written code for create `Multi User Chat` room and its working fine when i am using `Openfire` as server, but when i use `Prosody` as server it gives me error, as

**`Creation failed - Missing acknowledge of room creation.:`** 
i.e group is already exist. but it throws same error for any name(New Group Name).

if i replace `muc.create(name);` with `muc.join(name);` it creates group. but then i am unable to configure group/room properties.

below is my Prosody Config File:-

```
modules_enabled = {

-- Generally required
    "roster"; -- Allow users to have a roster. Recommended ;)
    "saslauth"; -- Authentication for clients and servers. Recommended if  you want to log in.
    --"tls"; -- Add support for secure TLS on c2s/s2s connections
    "dialback"; -- s2s dialback support
    "disco"; -- Service discovery

-- Not essential, but recommended
    "private"; -- Private XML storage (for room bookmarks, etc.)
    "vcard"; -- Allow users to set vCards

-- These are commented by default as they have a performance impact
    --"privacy"; -- Support privacy lists
    --"compression"; -- Stream compression

-- Nice to have
    "version"; -- Replies to server version requests
    "uptime"; -- Report how long server has been running
    "time"; -- Let others know the time here on this server
    "ping"; -- Replies to XMPP pings with pongs
    "pep"; -- Enables users to publish their mood, activity, playing music  and more
    "register"; -- Allow users to register on this server using a client  and change passwords

-- Admin interfaces
    "admin_adhoc"; -- Allows administration via an XMPP client that  supports ad-hoc commands
    --"admin_telnet"; -- Opens telnet console interface on localhost port  5582

-- HTTP modules
    "bosh"; -- Enable BOSH clients, aka "Jabber over HTTP"
    "http_files"; -- Serve static files from a directory over HTTP

-- Other specific functionality
    "groups"; -- Shared roster support
    --"announce"; -- Send announcement to all online users
    --"welcome"; -- Welcome users who register accounts
    --"watchregistrations"; -- Alert admins of registrations
    --"motd"; -- Send a message to users when they log in
    --"legacyauth"; -- Legacy authentication. Only used by some old  clients and bots.
};
 allow_registration = true -- Allow users to register new accounts

VirtualHost "localhost"

---Set up a MUC (multi-user chat) room server on conference.example.com:
Component "conference.localhost" "muc"
```

My Group Create Code is:-

```
                             MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(xmppConnection, room);

                          // Create the room
                          SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(2000);
                          String name = xmppConnection.getUser();
                          System.out.println("name:- " + name);
                          String name1 = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("@"));
                          System.out.println("name1:- " + name1);
                          System.out.println("group name:- " + grpName);
                          muc.create(name1);

                          // Get the the room's configuration form
                          Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
                          // Create a new form to submit based on the original form
                          Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
                          // Add default answers to the form to submit
                          for (Iterator<FormField> fields = form.getFields(); fields.hasNext();) {
                              FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();

                              if (!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType()) && field.getVariable() != null) {
                                  // Sets the default value as the answer
                                  submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
                              }
                          }
                         // muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);

                          Form f = new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT);
                          try {
                               muc.sendConfigurationForm(f);
                          } catch (XMPPException xe) {
                               System.out.println( "Error on sendConfigurationForm:- " +  xe);
                          }

                          // Sets the new owner of the room
                          List<String> owners = new ArrayList<String>();
                          owners.add(xmppConnection.getUser());
                          submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners);
                          submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
                          muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
```

where i am going wrong?

Comment: The unnecessary indentation of the java code makes it hard to read, please fix that.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by non-standard behavior of prosody's MUC plugin. Basically it behaves like a MUC room already exists, even if it's not the case.

You have to possibilites:

- Using Smack's (since 4.0) [MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(String)](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#createOrJoin(java.lang.String)), will succeed in this case. See also [SMACK-557](https://igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/SMACK-557)
- Setting prosody's [mod MUC property](https://prosody.im/doc/modules/mod_muc) `restrict_room_creation` to `true`, will make prosody behaves as specified in XEP-45

Since you want to configure the room, the only option is changing prosody's `restrict_room_creation` setting.

<sup>Note that there is another [issue in Smack's MUC code](https://igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/SMACK-604), that will be fixed in Smack 4.1 and [likely there will also be a workaround implemented in prosody.](https://code.google.com/p/lxmppd/issues/detail?id=438) But I don't think that this issue is related here, the info is just for completeness.</sup>